# Trying to diagnose bottleneck for apache

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, strace

I am trying to diagnose bottleneck for a apache(v 2.0.52) server using strace.

It looks like call to poll is slowing the process. Below is one example

poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 1, 120000) = 0 <119.996719>

ls -l /proc/pid/fd returns

10 -> socket:[somenumber]

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's expected: poll() waits for something to happen, the third argument is the millisecond timeout, nothing happened after ~120s...

In my experience logging, access control are DNS lookups are common causes of performance problems.